# Problem with USB multicasting in android

Tags: java, android, usb, multicast

Am trying to send out a multicast pakcet via usb interface of android.The code works well with wifi .
When I do msock = new MulticastSocket(); i get an exception **"java.net.SocketException: Network is unreachable"**
Am trying to multicast to address 239.255.255.250.
Also broadcast is perfectly ok .problem with multicast .
Am pasting the output of ifconfig usb0 below

## ifconfig usb0

ifconfig usb0
usb0: ip 192.168.42.129 mask 255.255.255.0 flags [up broadcast running multicast]

Is there anything extra to be done for USB to support multicasting?

Thanks  in advance 
Kozlov

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my question :)
After lot of tries we are now able to send multicast packets through USB.
Gave command dhcpcd in android device emulator and all started working ...I guess it has something to do with setting of route table(gateway info etc) .